# Proper style when writing a class within a class using a class template

Tags: c++, coding-style

my title is a little confusing, let me explain. I have written a linked like template class so as it can accept and type of data in c++ (i basically rewrote std::list but with a singly linked list), however now I'm trying to define a subclass Iterator within my List template, i understand how to implement all of this for the most part, my question is with regards to proper coding style. I understand with templates I am unable to break my class up into a separate header and source file, ok so i defined the class put a few function templates in there, then underneath wrote the functions... cool, but now with regards to my subclass Iterator, where should i write the code for these functions, there will not be much so should i write it simply within the class? or should i write it outside of my list class, but in the same file? if so how do i do this would the convention GenList::Iterator::next() work? or would it be something else (GenList is my linked list class, and next() would be the function i am writing for the Iterator)? or should i define my iterator outside of GenList but on the same header file? if this is unclear please ask for clarification of any part

Comment: C++11 has a singly-linked list, `std::forward_list`

Comment: MY teacher has yet to cover templates, but wants us to write god knows how many linked lists that are all exactly the same, so I thought I'd try to one up her, but she will be evil with her grading if my style is incorrect

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a pre written list i have to write my own, otherwise ide be done =)

Answer (score 0):

Style questions are off-topic, the coding style you use it up to you.  If you want to define the iterator type's member functions outside the class definition then the syntax would be :

```
template<typename T>
  GenList<T>::Iterator
  GenList<T>::Iterator::operator++(int)
  {
    Iterator tmp(*this);
    // increment *this
    return tmp;
  }
```

Personally I usually define small member functions like that inline in the class definition.

Is there a good reason to call the iterator `Iterator` rather than the conventional `iterator`?

Comment: "Is there a good reason to call the iterator Iterator rather than the conventional iterator?" And I thought style questions were off-topic! :-P

Comment: Interacting with many years worth of existing generic code that assumes a nested type called `iterator` is not about style, it's about code re-use and interoperability

Comment: Depends what code base you need to be interoperable with, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, obviously. "I have to conform to an unconventional coding standard" would be a valid answer to my question, but without a good reason it's better to follow convention and obey the [rule of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). I believe there is more C++ code using `iterator` than `Iterator`, do you disagree?

Comment: Well, the last three places I've worked all have coding standards that require all types to be capitalized, and each had a substantial existing code base. I'd say it's not a big issue since much generic code has a template argument for the iterator type rather than pulling out `typename T::iterator` in the body.

Comment: It's nice to know people still have time to spend making up very important rules like that in 2013 ;)

Comment: Presumably, they made it up long ago. One place even had an MFC-esque "Class names must start with C" rule. *shudder*